# What does * in a lambda expression inside map of spark mean?

Tags: lambda, pyspark

```
LabeledDocument = Row("id", "text", "label")
sc.parallelize([(0, "a b c d e spark", 1.0),
                 (1, "b d", 0.0),
                 (2, "spark f g h", 1.0),
                 (3, "hadoop mapreduce", 0.0)]) \
    .map(lambda x: LabeledDocument(*x)).first()
```

This code will give an output like

> Row(id=0, text='a b c d e spark', label=1.0)

But if you omit the * in the lambda expression i.e

```
sc.parallelize([(0, "a b c d e spark", 1.0),
                     (1, "b d", 0.0),
                     (2, "spark f g h", 1.0),
                     (3, "hadoop mapreduce", 0.0)]) \
        .map(lambda x: LabeledDocument(x)).first()
```

you will get the output as

> Row(id=(0, 'a b c d e spark', 1.0))

Can somebody tell me how the * works in separating the tuple and assigning  to each column of the Row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
print(x)
# => [1, 2, 3]
print(*x)
# => 1 2 3 # equivalent to print(1, 2, 3)
```

`*x` will distribute the list (or tuple) `x` into separate arguments.

In the same way, `LabeledDocument(x)` is equal to `LabeledDocument((0, "a b c d e spark", 1.0))` (with one tuple argument); but `LabeledDocument(*x)` is equal to `LabeledDocument(0, "a b c d e spark", 1.0)` (with three arguments: a number, a string and a number).

In Ruby, it is called "a splat", as the asterisk (`*`) looks like a splat, and as it splats the lists into function arguments and vice versa. In Python community, I am not sure if it has an agreed-upon name.

Read in detail in [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#index-36).